# break and get the contents of an url using php

Tags: php

www.example.com/12-23-34

for e.g. the above written is my page. Now what I need is to get 12, 23, and 34 seperatley. How can I achieve that?

Looked for the solution, but everywhere I got the solution to get 12-23-34 together.

Comment: Get them together and then explode with - and then do what ever you want to do with the result array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution for you:

```
$subURL = explode('/', $url); // separates url into  www.example.com and 12-23-34
$numbers = explode('-', $subURL[1]); // separates 12, 23 and 34.

echo $numbers[0]; // returns 12
echo $numbers[1]; // returns 23
echo $numbers[2]; // returns 34
```

Answer (score 2):

once you get "12-23-34", do an `$myArray = explode("-",$myString)`, where `$myArray` will have 3 item : 12, 23, and 34...

Answer (score 2):

You first need to get the current URI.

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This will get you `/12-23-34`.

Ignore the `/` by getting a substring.

```
$sub = substr($uri, 1);
```

Explode the substring into parts.

```
$parts = explode('-', $sub);
```

Loop through the parts to do what you want.

```
foreach ($parts as $part) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned remove the part you want - the path in your url and then explode it. You need to be sure your url always has a similar pattern.

```
$url = "www.example.com/12-23-34";
$pos = strrpos($url, "/");
$path = substr($url,$pos+1);
$my_numbers = explode("-",$path);
foreach ($my_numbers as $my_number) {
    print "$my_number<br>";
}
```

Comment: You could simply explode on `\ `, instead of strpos and substr

Comment: Cheers ... yes. I was thinking I'd just get the string after the last '/' since the URL could be www.example.com/path-to-stuff/12-23-34

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've used:

```
    <?php

$value = basename(__FILE__, '.php'); 

echo $value;

$numbers = explode('-', $value);

echo $numbers[0];
echo $numbers[1];
echo $numbers[2];

?>
```